# How exactly tech lover trait of vaulters work and when/where are shown benefits in result?

Tags: endless-legend

As described, perk adds +50% bonus to equipment, which is made from holy resource. Though, there's no notification or visible difference on attributes anytime anywhere, not in equipment screen, not even in battle. Or description of influence is very uncleverly hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How does Technolover work?**

What is affected (Increased by 50% if made with holy resource)

- Flat bonuses to most stats (+5 x on unit)

What is not affected

- Flat bonus to damage (see images below)
- Flat bonus to army stat (+5 x to army)
- Percentage stat increases (+5% x on unit)
- City accessory bonuses (+2 x per person in city)

**Where are the benefits visible?**

Only the final (total) attributes of a unit show the impact of Technolover. There are no mouse-over locations that reveal the contribution of it.

Base Unit (note that the equipped Tier 1 crossbow is giving +9 attack, +1 initiative)
[image]

Unit with Tier 3 crossbow (**resource not holy**) (gives stated +31 attack, +33 initiative, +14 damage)
[image]

Unit with Tier 3 crossbow (**resource is holy**) (further +16 attack, +17 initiative, no change damage)
[image]

Comment: Yeah, some time ago I found it on amplitude forums as well, but I totally forgot I asked it here. Thanks for bringing it on, though.